# iOS development

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to write supersimple iPhone application. It contains the list of buttons and if the user clicks one of these buttons, the application opens a new view with image.
My problem is that a lot of tutorials/books was created 2-3 years ago and I can't learn in parallel Objective C and understand compiler's changes. 
What will be better for my "buttons" menu? What can I read about it? Help pls

Comment: @Leo : From past two years no major change except Xcode+InterfaceBuilder and LLVM. Basics of Obj-C is same. Only advance things added.

Comment: Can you tell us what you have looked at. I don't understand how you can't pick it up from them, no real difference if anything it has been made easier.

Comment: Apple's own material is a good starting point and up to date.

Comment: I understand that if u now Objective C and Xcode, u don't see any changes. For example it's project structure: I havent "navigation-based Application" in my Xcode.

Comment: @Leo : All are there with slightly differnt name and better features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just look at storyboards tutorials, and you won't even need Objective-C for that kind of app.

*e.g.*: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1